# Проскролить в самый низ в чате

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте такая проблема есть блок с сообщениями высотой 400px в него добавлено css свойство `overflow-y: scroll;` и блок прокручивается вниз только на 400px а как сделать чтобы прокручивался в самый низ
вот сам код

```js
$('.message-block').animate({
  scrollTop: $('.message-block').height()
});
```

```css
.message-block {
    position: sticky;
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.text-sender-read {
    background-color: #8bda84;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5%;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.text-sender-unread {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 2px #3675d8;
 }
.sender{
 position: relative;
}

.incoming {
position: relative;
}

.text-incoming {
    background-color:rgba(173, 164, 172, 0.31);
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    float: right;
}

.page_square_photo {
        position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 82%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #b6cada;
    width: 70px;
    /* margin-left: 6px; */
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.page_photos_module {
    padding: 5px 0px 20px;
    height: 110px;
    
}
.inline-message {
        display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message-block">
<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">tyhrgedwsqa uyjthgr4fewq</p></div>
</div>

</div>



<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtrgeythrgfe</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rbtefdw</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtg4rfew</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">tyhrge</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rtgefw</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">ytyhrgwe tyhrgew</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtrg4e</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yuujthrge</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">hrtgefw</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">y4tre</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">jtyhr4e</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">ytehrg4ew</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">trew</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rthgweqq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rgefwq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yujthtr4e</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">y54r</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">trgedw</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jyhtg4re</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yutjhrg4e</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yujthgr4e</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">gfbvrweqq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">y5t4re</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jyhtgrteww</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">tyhrgew</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">ymtnhrgeww</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming"></p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">оноеркп4</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yt4r</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">nrtberewfdqq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">tjyhrgf4e</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jyhty4r</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">ujy4tr</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtg4re</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jhy4gtre</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">trhgfew</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">jyh5g4re</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jythrg4fe</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">tyrhge</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">hrtgewww</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">hngrtgrwe</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">hgrgtewqw</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">trhgweq</p></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот как я сделал, добавил еще один контейнер в ваших сообщениях теперь они в контейнере с классом `message-block-inner`. и у него высота автоматически ровно высоты его содержимого. И изменил прокрутку и сделал прокрутку до конца этого блока с классом (`message-block-inner`).

```js
$('.message-block').animate({
  scrollTop: $('.message-block-inner').height()
});
```

```css
.message-block {
    position: sticky;
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.text-sender-read {
    background-color: #8bda84;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5%;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.text-sender-unread {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 2px #3675d8;
 }
.sender{
 position: relative;
}

.incoming {
position: relative;
}

.text-incoming {
    background-color:rgba(173, 164, 172, 0.31);
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    float: right;
}

.page_square_photo {
        position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 82%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #b6cada;
    width: 70px;
    /* margin-left: 6px; */
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.page_photos_module {
    padding: 5px 0px 20px;
    height: 110px;
    
}
.inline-message {
        display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message-block">
<div class="message-block-inner">
<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">tyhrgedwsqa uyjthgr4fewq</p></div>
</div>

</div>



<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtrgeythrgfe</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rbtefdw</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtg4rfew</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">tyhrge</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rtgefw</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">ytyhrgwe tyhrgew</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtrg4e</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yuujthrge</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">hrtgefw</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">y4tre</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">jtyhr4e</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">ytehrg4ew</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">trew</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rthgweqq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rgefwq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yujthtr4e</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">y54r</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">trgedw</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jyhtg4re</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yutjhrg4e</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yujthgr4e</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">gfbvrweqq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">y5t4re</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jyhtgrteww</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">tyhrgew</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">ymtnhrgeww</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming"></p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">оноеркп4</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yt4r</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">nrtberewfdqq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">tjyhrgf4e</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jyhty4r</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">ujy4tr</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtg4re</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jhy4gtre</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">trhgfew</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">jyh5g4re</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jythrg4fe</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">tyrhge</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">hrtgewww</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">hngrtgrwe</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">hgrgtewqw</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">trhgweq</p></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: можете мне помочь почему у меня на сайте это отказывается работать

Comment: @Vadim ошибки есть коде `js`? как понять то что вы говорите не работает? крутиться но не в самый низ? или вообще не крутиться?

Comment: ошибок в консоли нет, вообще не крутиться пробовал и перед блоком ставить и после, но результата  нет

Comment: @Vadim Вы код `html` поменяли так как я?

Comment: да, блок добавил всё как у вас

Comment: @Vadim странно, а можете в этом месте вывести что нибуть в консоль, хочу узнать тот кусок кода работает вообще у вас.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60503/discussion-between-vadim-and-razmik-galstyan).

Answer (score 3):

```js
function animated_scroll(block, delay = 2222){
  let y = block.scrollTop; // Откуда начинаем прокручивать
  const dest = block.scrollHeight -block.offsetHeight;  // До куда надо прокрутить
  const interval = 1000 / 24; // 24 fps)) 
  const delta = (dest - y) * (interval/delay); // Сколько надо прокрутить за шаг, чтобы за время delay успеть прокрутить до куда надо
  // Поехали
  (function scroll(){
    if(y < dest){
      y += delta;
      block.scrollTop = y;
      setTimeout(scroll, interval);
    }// else мы уже на месте
  })();
}


animated_scroll(document.querySelector('.message-block'))
```

```css
.message-block {
    position: sticky;
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.text-sender-read {
    background-color: #8bda84;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5%;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.text-sender-unread {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 2px #3675d8;
 }
.sender{
 position: relative;
}

.incoming {
position: relative;
}

.text-incoming {
    background-color:rgba(173, 164, 172, 0.31);
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    float: right;
}

.page_square_photo {
        position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 82%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #b6cada;
    width: 70px;
    /* margin-left: 6px; */
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.page_photos_module {
    padding: 5px 0px 20px;
    height: 110px;
    
}
.inline-message {
        display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message-block">
<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">tyhrgedwsqa uyjthgr4fewq</p></div>
</div>

</div>



<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtrgeythrgfe</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rbtefdw</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtg4rfew</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">tyhrge</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rtgefw</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">ytyhrgwe tyhrgew</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtrg4e</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yuujthrge</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">hrtgefw</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">y4tre</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">jtyhr4e</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">ytehrg4ew</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">trew</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rthgweqq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">rgefwq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yujthtr4e</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">y54r</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">trgedw</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jyhtg4re</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yutjhrg4e</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yujthgr4e</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">gfbvrweqq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">y5t4re</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jyhtgrteww</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">tyhrgew</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">ymtnhrgeww</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming"></p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">оноеркп4</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">yt4r</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">nrtberewfdqq</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">tjyhrgf4e</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jyhty4r</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">ujy4tr</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">yhtg4re</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jhy4gtre</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">trhgfew</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">jyh5g4re</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">jythrg4fe</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">tyrhge</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">hrtgewww</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">hngrtgrwe</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming">hgrgtewqw</p></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="inline-message">

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="sender"><p class="text-sender-read">trhgweq</p></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

P.S. jQuery **не нужен**

Comment: можете мне помочь почему у меня на сайте это отказывается работать